# Fast and Editable JQuery Grid

Tags: jquery, performance, grid

I am looking for a fast, editable JQuery grid which can handle a good amount of records at reasonable speed.May you propose one or a suite from I can pick up such grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [Shield UI Grid Editing demos](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-editing/editing-restful-web-service).

The ShieldUI Grid widget has very powerful editing and other customization options.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend :

- [Kendo grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index)
- [datatables](https://www.datatables.net/)
- [jqgrid](http://jqgrid.com/)